# how to split numbers

Tags: r

I have a date format like this 
5170301, where it means 1st March 2017.And I have 5 attached to it 
I want the format of the date to be changed.
So can anyone help me in splitting that 5 from the date?

Answer (score 2):

We can use `substring` to read from the 2nd character onwards

```
v1 <- substring(df1$date, 2)
```

NOTE: It should work for `numeric/character/factor` class

Then we change it to `Date` class

```
v2 <- as.Date(v1, "%y%m%d")
```

and if needed change the `format`

```
format(v2,  "%d %b %Y")
```

---

Or as @thelatemail mentioned, it can be mentioned in the `format`

```
as.Date(df1$date, "5%y%m%d")
```

Comment: No need to remove the `5` - just add it into the format - `as.Date("5170301", format="5%y%m%d")`

Answer (score 0):

You can split it quite nicely with the stringr package

```
 Split <- stringr::str_split_fixed(string=Column_Name, pattern="5", n=2)
```

This will give two variables: one blank and one of your value after the "5" (170301)

Then can change it to the date as so:

```
 Date1 <- as.Date(format="%d%m%y", x = Split)
```